# Session.delete() not working

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to delete ROW in SQL DB by session.delete() on calling a RemoveProject Servlet where getting Parameters for which I want to delete Object from db.

```
SessionFactory sf=DataConnect.getConnect();
    Session sess=sf.openSession();
    Transaction tr=sess.beginTransaction();
    try{
    Query qur=sess.createQuery("from Project");
    org.hibernate.Criteria cr=sess.createCriteria(Project.class);
    //cr.add(Restrictions.eq("name",request.getParameter("name")));
    cr.add(Restrictions.idEq(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"))));
                        List obj=cr.list();

     for (Iterator iterator = obj.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
     {
        osl.pojo.Project devobj = (osl.pojo.Project) iterator.next(); 
         System.out.print("DELETING"+devobj.getName()+"from Project");
        sess.delete(devobj);



        tr.commit();System.out.println("ROW DELETED");
     }

    }catch(HibernateException he){ he.printStackTrace(); ;tr.rollback(); response.sendRedirect(request.getRequestURI());}
```

But it is not working I also Tried Flushing Session.

I am getting this Message in Glassfish Console.

```
***Info:   DELETING DATA_To_BE_DELETED from Project

WARN:   SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000

ERROR:   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'index=1' at line 1

Info:   HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
Severe:   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement***
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Database Column Name for the said Issue was conflicting with database property "index", so it was getting error on updating the Object Data back to the Sql , and in the SQL syntax it was causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are trying commit inside the `for` loop, so change it to outside the loop:

```
for (Iterator iterator = obj.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    osl.pojo.Project devobj = (osl.pojo.Project) iterator.next(); 
    System.out.print("DELETING"+devobj.getName()+"from Project");
    sess.delete(devobj);
}
tr.commit();
```

Comment: It has been resolved, the property name of my sql table was 'index'. So sql syntax was not working.